# What ingredient should I add to my cookies to increase shelf life?

Tags: baking, storage-lifetime, cookies

What ingredient should I add to my cookies to increase shelf life. I need my cookies, 6 months later to still be fresh (expiry date in 6 months).

Comment: You could try reading the ingredient list on commercial cookies.

Answer (score 7):

No ingredient will make a cookie last 6 months. Some types of cookies last longer than others: for example, [this recipe for biscotti](https://www.seriouseats.com/recipes/2018/12/almond-anise-biscotti-cookies.html) can keep up to 3 months if kept in an airtight container in a cool place.

But again, there is no way to take a generic recipe for cookies and amend it to last this long. Something like American-style chocolate chip cookies simply has too much fat and moisture to keep. A possible alternative is to freeze cookie dough, possibly in pre-portioned scoops, and bake a fresh batch when you need them.

Comment: If that answer is what you consider acceptable, you might want to click on it to accept it as *the* answer.

Comment: You can also freeze baked cookies pretty well.

Answer (score -3):

I know this is three years later, but if you haven't found a solution (I'm on the journey myself, currently, lol) look into BHT/BHA, sodium benzoate, or citric acid. I just started adding potassium sorbate into my items. We will see what happens. Lol.

Comment: Welcome to the site – when it comes to food safety, we defer to official guidance and this suggestion would not yield safe food that lasts a long time by that standard. Bear in mind that no commercial cookie would claim to be safe to eat six months after opening, even with the benefit of commercial preservatives, production methods and a lab to test their product.